# h2 database query blocks connection pool

Tags: database, performance, concurrency, h2

I'm trying to make a large SELECT of 30000+ rows from 2 joined tables. The query takes about 12 seconds on my machine without fetching of rows. But the strange thing is that during the query execution I can not obtain any connection from pool and execute another query in parallel. All the pool becomes blocked during the query execution. In stack trace I found that a connection is trying to execute ROLLBACK before it will be returned that blocks the execution until the SELECT query will be completed:

```
"web-thread-6" #110 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fa86c00a000 nid=0x6fd0 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fa8ba727000]
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
  at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251)
- waiting to lock <0x00000005c94ccf18> (a org.h2.engine.Database)
  at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.rollbackInternal(JdbcConnection.java:1514)
  at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.rollback(JdbcConnection.java:502)
- locked <0x00000005ca55c870> (a org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection)
  at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcXAConnection.getConnection(JdbcXAConnection.java:107)
  at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnectionNow(JdbcConnectionPool.java:229)
  at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnection(JdbcConnectionPool.java:199)
```

My H2 database version is 1.4.192. The database is running in embedded mode with an URL jdbc:h2:file:dir/db. The query is readonly: ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY.

And my question is that if H2 does not support query execution in parallel even readonly, or I'm doing something wrong?

Thanx,
Antón